# Question on Probability

Tags: probability, self-study, proportion

I was attempting to solve a question on finding the probability that a randomly selected person had an income of $50,000 or more would be audited, based on information on the table below:

[image]

My attempt was to take the proportion of those with income more than $50,000 and multiply it with the percentage audited.

> **Proportion of those earning more than $50,000**: 11.4 / 101.5 = 0.11231
>
> 0.11231 * 2.24 = 0.2516

However, my answer was slighty off from the provided answer of 0.2394. Am I even on the right track with the method that I am using? Appreciate any advice please.

Comment: It seems that the table already gives the answer: because it says that $2.24\%$ of all filers with incomes of 50K or more are audited, that's the chance that a randomly chosen filer in that income group will be audited. Because that is far from the answer provided you, I would guess the question differs in some important--but perhaps subtle--way from how you have phrased it here.  Could you tell us *exactly* what the question asks?

Comment: Thank you whuber. The question says that "the table describes 101.5 million US federal tax returns filed with the Internal Revenue Service (IRS) in 1987 and the percentage of those returns that were audited by the IRS. If it were known that the randomly selected tax filter has been audited, what is the probability that the person had an income of $50,000 or more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As whuber suggests it looks like you have probably very slightly mitsranscribed the question. It's very important to get every word right when dealing with these questions, because moving, adding or deleting even a single word can change the implied conditioning of events completely.

If the question asks something like "the probability that a randomly selected auditee would have an income of $50,000 or more", then the answer provided to you makes sense.

You could do that kind of question by computing the number audited in each income group, and then converting to a proportion of the total audited which are in each group.

Comment: Thanks Glen. May I kindly clarify that "the answer provided makes sense" was referring to 0.2516?

Comment: I meant the answer that you called "the provided answer" in your own question. I simply repeated your phrase.

Comment: I have clarified by adding 'to you' after 'provided'